# How do you get a second canvas to appear on a tkinter Toplevel window when inside a class?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, canvas, toplevel

I'm using Tkinter to create an application, and with this Dashboard class, I'm trying to get a pop out window to show another canvas, so I can use create_image and tag_bind on the pop out. The result I'm currently getting is that the second canvas appears over the first canvas instead of in the pop out window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Dashboard(tk.Tk):
    """
    Configures, and displays the Dashboard
    """

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.config(width=1440, height=1024)

        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="#343333", height=1024, width=1440, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief="ridge")
        canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

        # Captures the background image for the canvas
        image_path = "dashboard_background.png"
        self.background_img = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_path)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=self.background_img)

        def logoutbuttonClicker():
            pop = Toplevel(self)
            pop.geometry('537x273')
            pop.config(height=273, width=537)

            logout_canvas = tk.Canvas(canvas, bg="#ffffff", height=273, width=537, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief="ridge")
            logout_canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

            self.logout_background_img = PhotoImage(file=f"logout_background.png")
            logout_canvas.create_image(268.5, 136.5, anchor='nw', image=self.logout_background_img)
            
            self.logout_yes_img = PhotoImage(file=f"logout_yes.png")
            self.logout_no_img = PhotoImage(file=f"logout_no.png")

        logout_image_path = "dashboard_logout.png"
        self.logout_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=logout_image_path)
        logoutButton = canvas.create_image(45, 950, anchor='nw', image=self.logout_image)
        canvas.tag_bind(logoutButton, "<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: logoutbuttonClicker())

def main():
    app = Dashboard()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[This is how it currently appears in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4P2C.png)

Comment: You should make `logout_canvas` a child of `pop` instead of `canvas`.

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense! Thank you, @acw1668, it looks to have worked.